# Solr More Like This results narrowed down by facet field

Tags: solr, solrnet, faceted-search, morelikethis

I have a single Solr instance for indexing multiple sites content.
While indexing I am populating Website field to be able to perform faceted search on that field for every particular website...and that works ok.

Though, if I use Solr MLT feature I get results from all websites, and I want to narrow MLT results down just to the single website.

Is it possible to define facet for the Solr MLT or is there any other better way to achieve the same?

If Solr supports that, is it also available in solrnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr 3.1 doesn't support filters on the MoreLikeThis component ([issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2351)). You have to use the [MoreLikeThis handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler), <strike>but this handler is not currently implemented in SolrNet ([issue here](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=143)).</strike> available as of 0.4.0 beta 1

Comment: Thanks Mauricio! I've just started using Solr and solrnet. I'll look more into solrnet implementation and eventually try to implement some of the new features. MLT handler could be the one.